# Crystal Reports If-Statement

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on a project in Crystal Reports where I'm trying to suppress a section based off whether data is present or not. I'm running into an issue where the Boolean I'm basing the suppression on through an If statement is being activated even though the if statement shouldn't be entered

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared BooleanVar suppress_section;
If NOT (ISNULL({Orders.Data_Entry_Date})) THEN
"ENTERED"
```

This will not print out ENTERED, however

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared BooleanVar suppress_section;
If NOT (ISNULL({Orders.Data_Entry_Date})) THEN
(suppress_section := false)
```

This will set suppress_section to False.

Just wondering why this happens as it is not logical to me.
Thank you.

Comment: you need to be more specific about question.....are you testing both formulas for the same data? in other case where did you place the formulas...I see you are toomuch complicating your formulas.... you can see some easy way to accomplish the task.. Let me know on whether you get same result on same data?

Comment: If you want your Details section suppressed when that field is null then all you need to do is add the section suppression formula `isnull({Orders.Data_Entry_Date})`

Comment: @Siva The idea was that I have to run a subreport to generate a section of my report, however I have to run it twice as there are two different tables that the data could be stored in, or in the case that there is no matching data in either table I wanted it to print a formatted blank section to fill in data. I realize that I can suppress the report if there is no data, however it leaves me the case that if there is no data in either table, that whole section of the report is removed. So I thought that if I could pass back a shared variable after the subreport is run I could suppress w/ cond.

Comment: @Ryan Taylor Thats right...one question here if there is no data the report is blank....what will you supress in that case...if you have some data and need to hide then you can apply supress condition. If there is no data what is the need to apply supress condition...I hope i have understood correctly...let me know if you are doing something different

Comment: @Siva So the subreport is a formatted form that we give to customers to fill out, if we already have data in our system we want it to automatically fill out the sections of the form, however if we don't have the information in our system we want the subreport to just come up blank. However I have to run the subreport twice because we have two different versions of this form but the customer only does 1. So I want it to either display one or the other and not both, and if there is nothing at all, just display one empty section not two.

Comment: That is the logic if none of thendub report is blank how come there is a difference if one section is blank or both sections are blank...what effect ot have when customer view the reports

Answer (score 0):

there is formula field in the Crystals report.In the formula section there is option controls structure.

If condition then true_part else false_part